# How to setUp UiTableViewController below the battery bar

Tags: swift3, xcode8

newBie here. I have added an UItableViewController into storyBoard. I use this as a setting page.

HomeVC ---->  Setting VC

In code : I use the below code to bring the tableView below the battery Bar:

```
 self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20,left: 0,bottom: 0,right: 0)
```

Problem:

How to move the TableView down below the battery bar so that I can add a button above the table in StoryBoard

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you should use a normal view controller and drag a table on the view controller this way you can make the table size whatever you like. This will also allow you to place buttons wherever you like.

Don't forget to assign the TableViewDataSource and TableViewDelegate to your view controller.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

After doing some search on UiTableViewController, to use it as setting page I have to set static cell to it. This UiTableViewController will occupy the entire view.
To set the tableView below the battery icon, 
use:self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20,left: 0,bottom: 0,right: 0)

However, No need to do so. In the first TableViewSection, you can create a few tableView cell, just leave the first cell blank which acts as a margin below the battery bar.